# Pass a vue component to a child component

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a Vue component that will accept a component as parameter to display data, but I have trouble figuring out how to make it work. If I register the display component globally (using Vue.component()), it works, but if I register it locally, I get the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <my-link> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
```

Can anybody tell me how to make this work with local registration?

Main Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <my-list :items="items" :renderer="renderer"></my-list>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import MyList from './my-list'
export default {
    components: {
        'my-list': MyList,
        'my-link': {
            props: { data: Object },
            template: '<span>{{ data.Name }}</span>'
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            items: [
                { id: 1, Name: 'One' },
                { id: 2, Name: 'Two' }
            ],
            renderer: 'my-link'
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

MyList Component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
            <div :is="renderer" :data="item"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: { 
        items: Array,
        renderer: String
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to add `import MyLink from './my-link'` to the top of the script in the MyList Component if you want to be able to use the the `my-link` component in that scope

Comment: @thanksd There is no './my-link'. Plus I want to be able to use any component: MyList shouldn't need to know which components it can use.

Comment: Ah, I was misreading my-list vs my-link

Comment: Why not use a slot?

Comment: @BertEvans you're right slots would be the way to go in this case

Comment: Well this is an oversimplified example of what I wanna do... I'm creating a data-grid and I want to be able to specify a component for the cells for an specific column... I don't think slots would work in this case.

Comment: @laurian You might want to look at the source of this [example](https://codepen.io/andrewcourtice/pen/woQzpa?editors=1010). Slots are exactly what he uses for custom cells.

Comment: @laurian Here is the [github](https://github.com/andrewcourtice/vuetiful/tree/master/src/components/datatable#cell-templates).

Comment: @BertEvans awesome! I was able to make it work with slots... you're right: that's much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing this warning because you have not registered `my-link` in the scope of the component you are trying to use it in. You registered `my-link` in the Main component, but the MyList component doesn't have access to that scope.

Moving the component definition of `my-link` to the `components` property of the MyList component will fix the issue.

---

Alternatively, you could create a new single-file component for the `my-link` component, and import it wherever you want to use it. Just like you do for the `my-list` component.

---

If you want the `my-link` component to be globally accessible, you'll need to register it via `Vue.component` wherever you are instantiating the root Vue instance (probably in `src/main.js` if you used `vue-cli` to set up your project):

```
Vue.component('my-link', {
  props: { data: Object },
  template: '<span>{{ data.Name }}</span>'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  ...
});
```

---

If you *really* want to pass a component in to a child component, without registering to that child component, you can [pass the component definition as a property](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/yXpPxX?editors=1010), as suggested by @BertEvans.

Comment: I forgot to add the 'my-list' component... Sorry for that. I updated my question.

Comment: Is there no other way to do it? I could pass the component as an object, like
renderer: { template: .... }
but then how can I use it on MyList?

Comment: See my updated answer. Those are the three ways you could do it. I don't believe there's any other way.

Comment: Presumably you could pass the object definition as a property.

Comment: @BertEvans can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @BertEvans you could also pass registered components via `$options.components` https://codepen.io/anon/pen/awEVRj?editors=1010 Either way seems like a code smell to me...

Comment: I agree reaching into $options.components would be a code smell, but I could be convinced on passing the definition. Wouldn't be my first option.

Comment: @BertEvans thanks! If you wanna make an answer out of it, I'll mark it as accepted.
Though why do you guys think it's bad practice?

Comment: @thanksd can edit it in if he wants. I was just spitballing. I think slots are the way to go.