# VueJs: Pass Dynamic Components as props to another Component and render them

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to build a table component.

I want to define and pass the column metadata for the grid as an array prop and also pass the actual data as another prop to the grid.

I was able to achieve that without many issues.

But, now I would like to pass a dynamic component as a part of each column definition so that the user can define/control the way the cell gets rendered (content with edit delete buttons in same cell etc.)

Is there a way to pass a dynamic component as a prop and then have this component rendered?

```
<parent-comp>
  <tr class="" v-for="result in dataSource">
    <template v-for="column in columns">
      <td>
        <template v-if="column.customComponent">
          ######## How do I render this customComponent ########
        </template>
      </td>
    </template>
  </tr>
</parent-comp>
```

where the dataSource data can be something like

```
[
  columns: [{
    name: "something",
    customComponent: SomeCustomComponent
  }, {
    name: "another thing",
    customComponent: AnotherOtherCustomComponent
  }]
]
```

Will be happy to elaborate/clarify on this if the ask above is not clear.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components

Comment: @thanksd Thank you, however in my case I will not what components will passed to the parent-comp before hand to have the components listed in the `components` property

Comment: You don't have to if you pass the component definition.

Comment: This was [our discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44809107/38065) The last time this came up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, you can use a dynamic component in your template and pass the definition of the component in your property.

```js
console.clear()

const ColumnOne = {
  template: `<h1>I am ColumnOne</h1>`
}

const ColumnTwo = {
  template: `<h1>I am ColumnTwo</h1>`
}

Vue.component("parent-comp",{
  props:["columns"],
  template:`
    <div>
      <component v-for="column in columns" 
                 :is="column.customComponent" 
                 :key="column">
      </component>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    columns:[{
      name: "something",
      customComponent: ColumnOne
    }, {
      name: "another thing",
      customComponent: ColumnTwo
    }]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <parent-comp :columns="columns"></parent-comp>
</div>
```

Comment: And if he needs to pass in props, he could do that like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ro1j8xmv/